# Hardcoded value works fine but when pass from parameter does not give same result in i-Report

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am using i-Report 5.6.0 to design my report. It is working fine when I am giving the value hard coded for the parameter `$P{collectedStudentIds}`. But when I am sending this value as this parameter it does not show the same result. Although the passed parameter value is the same as I have used as hard coded. What can I try next to solve this?

My query is given below :

```
    select cn.id as class_id, cn.class_name, s.id as student_id, s.name
from student s
inner join class_name cn
 on (s.class_name_id = cn.id)

where 1=1
and s.id not in (
    $P{collectedStudentIds}
)
order by cn.id, s.id
```

And my hard coded value which is same passed by parameter :

```
1,3,4,8,10,11,12,17,18,22
```

Comment: It may be treating it as a string and enclosing it in quotes.  Don't know if you can pass it in as an array as I don't know the package your using.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.

Just use the parameter with this sign when pass string literal from server

```
$P!{collectedStudentIds}
```

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1030546/how-pass-string-xin-using-url